# Angular:Trying to use Ng-if in HTML table

Tags: angular

I have an html table row that looks like this...

```
  <tr *ngFor='let moloc of moratoriumswithlocs'>
        <td>{{moloc.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{moloc.SystemId}}</td>
        <td>{{moloc.DateEffective | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
        <td>{{moloc.DateExpiration | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
        <td>{{moloc.StateAbbreviation}}</td>
        <td>{{moloc.County}}</td>
        <td>{{moloc.City}}</td>
        <td>{{moloc.Zip}}</td>
        <td>{{moloc.ReasonId}}</td>
    </tr>
```

I want to write a conditional where it tests for SystemId (the second cell in the row)  and if its equal to 1 , the cell will say "XXX" . If its not equal to 1 it will say "YYY" . Is there a way in the second td to do this using ng If or do I need to do this another way? Any help or direction would be most appreciated.
--Jason

Comment: `<td *ngIf="moloc.SystemId == true">XXX</td><td *ngIf="moloc.SystemId == false">YYY</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways.

You could use a couple of ngIf (one for each case):

```
<td *ngIf="moloc.SystemId == 1">XXX</td>
<td *ngIf="moloc.SystemId != 1">YYY</td>
```

Or use the ternary operator:

```
<td>{{ moloc.SystemId == 1 ? 'XXX' : 'YYY' }}</td>
```